# Future chrome push notification

Tags: javascript, web, push-notification, notifications

I'm trying to implement a "notify me when " button on my site and I wondered if there's a way to do that with push notifications.

I'd like to do that for as many platforms as possible (chrome, edge, firefox, safari, ios-safari).
I couldn't find any information on future notifications, is there a way to do that? If not, is there a creative way to notify clients about future events?

Comment: Can you be more specfic? Like facebook's (1) new alert or like gmails desktop notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement something like that cross platform

[image]